# Twitter boostrap / jQuery alert firing twice - what am I doing wrong

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am building my first Ruby on Rails application (not a tutorial) which is a port of an old VB6 application. I have a text box which upon exit from it (losing focus) needs to calculate a persons age, and if the text_box is not blank then some radiobuttons need to be disabled.
I can get this working, however when I was prototyping this I had an alert message. When the text_box lost focus the alert would fire twice. What am I doing wrong, and/or what is causing this.

While I could just remove the alert, I am concerned that if I call a script to calculate the persons age then it will fire twice as well.

Here is my code:

Partial *(_person_registration.html.erb)*

```
<fieldset>
  <legend id="age_calcs">Age</legend>

      <div class="span12">
        <div class="span1">

          <%= text_field_tag :age %>
          <%= label_tag :age, "Age" %>

        </div>
        <div class="span10 form-inline">

          <%= f.radio_button :age_unit, "years"  %> <!-- #, :checked => true, :disabled => true -->
          <%= f.label :age_unit_years, "Years" %>
          <%= f.radio_button :age_unit, "months" %>
          <%= f.label :age_unit_months, "Months" %>

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="span12">
        <div class="form-inline">
<!--         <fieldset> -->
            <%= label_tag :age_group, "Age Group" %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:age_group, 0, :checked => true ) %>
            <%= f.label(:age_group_adult, "Adult", :value => '0' ) %>          
            <%= f.radio_button(:age_group, 1) %>
            <%= f.label(:age_group_child, "Child", :value => '1') %>
            <%= f.radio_button(:age_group, 2) %>
            <%= f.label(:age_group_infant, "Infant", :value => '2' ) %>

<!--         </fieldset> -->

        </div>
      </div>
</fieldset>
```

*people.js*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("input[type='text']#age").bind('focusout', function() {
        {alert ('Age calculation - Not yet delivered')}
        if ($(this).val().length != 0 ) {
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_0').attr('disabled', true);
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_1').attr('disabled', '');
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_2').attr('disabled', '');      
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_child_3').attr('disabled', 'true');
            // alert ('Age calculations');
        }
        else {
            // alert ('Else portion');
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_0').attr('disabled', false);
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_1').attr('disabled', false);
            $('input#patient_patient_detail_attributes_age_group_2').attr('disabled', false);       
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    })
});
```

Additionally, can I call a ruby method when the focus is lost to perform the age calculation, or do I have to do the calculation in javascript?